# Custom code calculated value not displaying in EXCEL when export from SSRS

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, excel-2010, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a custom array code in SSRS to get particular month value and use it in another tablix.

```
public function AddArrRevTotal(a as double) as double
arrRev(iarrRev) = a
iarrRev= iarrRev+1
return a
end function

public function GetArrRevTotal(i as int32) as double
return arrRev(i)
end function
```

When it renders, I can see the value in SSRS report viewer. But when I export that to EXCEL, it shows "$0.0". 
Could anyone please help me how to get the value in excel? I tried changing the DataElementOutput property.But it did not work.TIA[image]. I tried to copy the code.But I could not able to do that because of syntax errors. From the sample data I need to get prior month that is December revenue to use it in another calculation.

Comment: I have added some sample data. Code I have copied as image file.

Comment: Now I found why the first time i got syntax errors. I have to  type it first and then click {} the button for code formatting. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and perseverance. fwiw, selecting the code and tapping [Ctrl]+K does the same thing.